# What's the function of “keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {” in the config file of Tensorflow Object Detection API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I use the Tensorflow Object Detection API to create an AI for Faster-RCNN.
[GitHub:Tensorflow/models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git)

What kind of resizing function does "keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {" in the config file have?

I prepared images of 1920 x 1080 pixels and set "min dimension:" and "max dimension:" described immediately after "keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {" in the config file to 768 respectively.

In this case, the 1920x1080 pixel image would be resized to 768x768 pixels and input to the CNN. At this time, will the original ratio of the image (16: 9) be maintained? Namely, when the image is resized to 768x768 pixels, will the long sides of the image be converted to 768 pixels and black bars will be added in the margin of the image?

Or does the image ratio change from 16: 9 to 1: 1 and become contort when this setting?

If anyone knows about this, please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: See the code: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/316a297704c94a76efedb1654886d7bb44be35e6/research/object_detection/core/preprocessor.py#L2868

Also, pay attention that you cannot specify the same value for min_dimension and max_dimension: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/builders/image_resizer_builder.py#L78

Comment: This docstring can be helpful: 
Returns:
    Note that the position of the resized_image_shape changes based on whether
    masks are present.
    resized_image: A 3D tensor of shape [new_height, new_width, channels],
      where the image has been resized (with bilinear interpolation) so that
      min(new_height, new_width) == min_dimension or
      max(new_height, new_width) == max_dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the different fields of the configuration files can be seen following this link: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/protos

The *keep_aspect_ratio_resizer* field is in image_resizer.proto and state the following:

```
// Configuration proto for image resizer that keeps aspect ratio.
message KeepAspectRatioResizer {
  // Desired size of the smaller image dimension in pixels.
  optional int32 min_dimension = 1 [default = 600];

  // Desired size of the larger image dimension in pixels.
  optional int32 max_dimension = 2 [default = 1024];

  // Desired method when resizing image.
  optional ResizeType resize_method = 3 [default = BILINEAR];

  // Whether to pad the image with zeros so the output spatial size is
  // [max_dimension, max_dimension]. Note that the zeros are padded to the
  // bottom and the right of the resized image.
  optional bool pad_to_max_dimension = 4 [default = false];

  // Whether to also resize the image channels from 3 to 1 (RGB to grayscale).
  optional bool convert_to_grayscale = 5 [default = false];

  // Per-channel pad value. This is only used when pad_to_max_dimension is True.
  // If unspecified, a default pad value of 0 is applied to all channels.
  repeated float per_channel_pad_value = 6;
}
```

Hence it is your choice to add padding (black bars) by adding the *pad_to_max_dimension: true* in your config file. Otherwise it should keep the aspect ratio.

Comment: Thank you for giving me some advice. I didn't mention "pad_to_max_dimension: true" in the config file, so the 1920x1080 pixel image was converted to 768x768 pixels, and the aspect ratio was changed to 1: 1?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm just starting out with programming and machine learning, so I may be asking a mess of questions.

Comment: Well it'll probably stretch the image according to the new size! If you put the padding the image will look the same but smaller and with black pixels on the bottom and the right. I can't be 100% sure though but there is probably a way to look at it if you dig into the code.